# Model Null when call Ajax .NET Core 3.1

Tags: api, post, model, asp.net-core-3.1

### I submitted the data with the specific model, but the server did not receive it.

[image]

### Conversely, if I send an object type and cast it to List, it receives it.

### [image]

### Here is my code

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ImportFromExcel([FromBody]object data)
{
    if (data == null)
        return BadRequest();
    List<ImportExcelModel> listExcel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ImportExcelModel>>(data.ToString());
    if (listExcel == null || listExcel.Count == 0)
        return Json(new { Result = false });
    return Json(new { Result = _services.ImportFromExcel(listExcel) });
}
```

### Finally

**For ASP.NET MVC5 I post it to the server. And it works fine. But for .NET Core 3.1 it doesn't work.
This has nothing to do with configuration in the Startup.cs file?**

Comment: Check the convertion from object to your model class. Have you tried to cast the object to the model class directly in the 2nd sceenshot?

Comment: How do I pass the object directly on post using Ajax?

Comment: Could you try IEnumerable<> instead of List<>?

Comment: Additionally, could you add the Startup.cs? And the JSON-Body(data as string).